# The field 'xxx' must be a number in MVC DropDownList

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-select

I use a `DropDownList` in my MVC application. There is a problem when I load my page: there is a error message shown in the HTML source of the `DropDownList`.

Please see this image:

[image]

This field is already set to allow null in the DB and

```
using System.Web;
using Nop.Web.Framework;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Mvc;
using Nop.Web.Validators.Customer;

namespace Nop.Web.Models.Customer
{
 public class FileUploadModel : BaseNopEntityModel
 {
    public CustomerNavigationModel NavigationModel { get; set; }
    public string ControlID { get; set; }
    public int? EventID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Events { get; set; }
    public string SpeakerFile { get; set; }
    public string FirmFile { get; set; }
    public string LogoFile { get; set; }
    public string PresentFile { get; set; }
    public string Present2File { get; set; }

    public string SpeakerFileUrl { get; set; }
    public string FirmFileUrl { get; set; }
    public string LogoFileUrl { get; set; }
    public string PresentFileUrl { get; set; }
    public string Present2FileUrl { get; set; }

    public string SpeakerSubmit { get; set; }
    public string FirmSubmit { get; set; }
    public string LogoSubmit { get; set; }
    public string PresentSubmit { get; set; }
    public string Present2Submit { get; set; }
 }
}
```

in model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't your DropDown list be bound to Events, rather than the EventID?

```
public int? EventID { get; set; }
public IEnumerable<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> Events { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Those `data-*` attributes are added by the unobtrusive validation framework. Since your `EventID` property is declared as an integer the framework validates the format ad adds those attributes. It is nullable integer so there's no `data-val-required` attribute being added.

Comment: so how to make the validation pass in this case? Wont the validation take the `dropdown` values as `numbers` ?

Comment: But validation should pass. Those attributes are used only by the unobtrusive validation framework in case there were some other values in the dropdown which are not integers. But from what I can see your dropdown contains correct integer values, so no error message should ever be shown to the user.

Answer (score 1):

whats an issue in this. As you are defining int in model its showing this message . And you had define it as nullable, if you have not than there could be also message for required. " The field is required.

Comment: please never use bold letters in answer

Comment: There is no Required attribute in my Model.